# Are closed timelike curves generic feature of ANEC-violating stress-energy tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, causality, time-travel

Kip Thorne has [shown](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~kip/scripts/ClosedTimelikeCurves-II121.pdf) that in order to create closed timelike curves (CTCs), one needs stress-energy tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$ that violates averaged null energy condition (ANEC).

Will $T^{\mu\nu}$ with such property (violation of ANEC) generically create CTCs or does it have to satisfy another such relatively simply definable property in order to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ellis-Bronnikov wormhole, with topology $\mathbb{R}^2 \times S^2$ and metric

\begin{equation}
ds^2 = - dt^2 + dl^2 + (b^2 + l^2) d\Omega^2
\end{equation}

violates the ANEC and possesses no closed timelike curves (nor can it be made to develop any since the topological handle is between two different spacetimes and not the same one), as can be seen by its energy density, $\rho = -\frac{b^2}{(b^2 + l^2)^2}$, which is always negative and so its integral over any curve will be negative.